# Comparar Datos en Oracle

Tags: base-de-datos, oracle

Tal como dice el titulo necesito hacer una comparación de datos. La situación se plantea de la siguiente forma. Tengo una función que recibe un parámetro ese parámetro será procesado para eliminar ciertos caracteres del mismo.

La función es la siguiente:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fReemplazaCeros(cPoliza IN VARCHAR2)
RETURN VARCHAR2
IS
    retorno VARCHAR2 (50);
    contador INTEGER (10);

BEGIN
    contador := 1;

     WHILE SUBSTR(cPoliza, contador, contador) = 0  LOOP

     contador := contador + 1;
     dbms_output.put_line('-> ' || SUBSTR(cPoliza, contador));
     retorno:= SUBSTR(cPoliza, contador);

     END LOOP;

    RETURN retorno;
END;
```

Básicamente lo que sucede con esta función es que una cadena va a ser revisada carácter por carácter en busca de que se busque un 0 en dicha cadena, para que al final de todo, todos los ceros que se encuentren en esta cadena (en principio) sean quitados.

Cuando hago pruebas con esta función sale lo siguente:

```
SELECT fREEMPLAZACEROS('00000273623413') FROM DUAL;

-> 0000273623413
-> 000273623413
-> 00273623413
```

Esta función podría decirse que funciona a medias, pues solo encuentra tres 0 y sale del ciclo while,la pregunta es ¿Hay algo mal en esta función que ocasione la salida del ciclo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Veo 2 problemas en tu función.

1. La condición del `while` es `SUBSTR(cPoliza, contador, contador) = 0`. Si lo vemos *paso a paso*, con la entrada `'00000273623413'`, creo que verás el problema.

   - Contador vale 1, sería `SUBSTR(cPoliza, 1, 1)`, es decir '0'
   - Contador vale 2, sería `SUBSTR(cPoliza, 2, 2)`, es decir '00'
   - Contador vale 3, sería `SUBSTR(cPoliza, 3, 3)`, es decir '000'
   - Contador vale 4, sería `SUBSTR(cPoliza, 4, 4)`, es decir '0027'
2. Comparas una cadena de texto con un número. Esto fuerza al motor a hacer una conversión de tipo, con lo cual el rendimiento es poco óptimo.

Para mantener tu lógica, Lo que tú en realidad quieres es:

- Comparar cadenas de una longitud fija de `1` caracter.
- Comparar con el caracter `'0'`, para evitar la conversión de tipo.

En código, sería algo como esto:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fReemplazaCeros(cPoliza IN VARCHAR2)
RETURN VARCHAR2
IS
  retorno VARCHAR2 (50);
  contador INTEGER (10);

BEGIN
  contador := 1;

  WHILE SUBSTR(cPoliza, contador, 1) = '0' 
  LOOP
     contador := contador + 1;
     dbms_output.put_line('-> ' || SUBSTR(cPoliza, contador));
     retorno:= SUBSTR(cPoliza, contador);
  END LOOP;
  RETURN retorno;
END;
```

Comment: Woow, tienes razón no lo había visto así, muchas gracias por tu ayuda.